# Cannot compile Minted environment with TeXStudio

Tags: latex, pygments

I'm writing on a Latex Document and want to have some Code Highlighting. So I decided to use the minted package. But i cant get the minimal example to work.

The Pygments package is installed via anaconda under the path /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages. Running pygmentize -V from the CLI works.

Im using TexStudio and also have included the "-shell-escape" in the Commands.

But anyway I'm getting the following errors

```
line 94: Paragraph ended before \zap@space was complete....\edef\@tempa{\expandafter\zap@space\@tempa
line 104: Paragraph ended before \ip@only@six was complete. ...ef\@tempc{\expandafter\ip@only@six\@tempa
line 104: Undefined control sequence. ...expandafter\ip@only@six\@tempa------\@nil
line 5: Package minted Error: You must have `pygmentize' installed to use this package. \begin{document}
line 11: Package minted Error: Missing Pygments output; \inputminted wasor may be using frozencache with a missing file. \end{minted}^^M
line 11: Package minted Error: Missing Pygments output; \inputminted wasor may be using frozencache with a missing file. \end{minted}^^M
line 11: Package minted Error: Missing Pygments output; \inputminted wasor may be using frozencache with a missing file. \end{minted}
```

The example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minted}{c}
        int main() {
            printf("hello, world");
            return 0;
        }
    \end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Operating System is macOS Mojave.

Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Update: As requested in the comments, here is the complete log

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.10.21)  21 OCT 2019 16:34
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**PraxisphaseAufsatz.tex
(./PraxisphaseAufsatz.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 1
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/08/27 v1.4j Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2019/08/27 v1.4j Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/minted/minted.sty
Package: minted 2017/07/19 v2.5 Yet another Pygments shim for LaTeX

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fvextra/fvextra.sty
Package: fvextra 2019/02/04 v1.4 fvextra - extensions and patches for fancyvrb

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2019/09/21 v2.5h e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count88
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty
Package: fancyvrb 2019/01/15

Style option: `fancyvrb' v3.2a <2019/01/15> (tvz)
\FV@CodeLineNo=\count89
\FV@InFile=\read1
\FV@TabBox=\box27
\c@FancyVerbLine=\count90
\FV@StepNumber=\count91
\FV@OutFile=\write3
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/upquote/upquote.sty
Package: upquote 2012/04/19 v1.3 upright-quote and grave-accent glyphs in verba
tim
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lineno/lineno.sty
Package: lineno 2005/11/02 line numbers on paragraphs v4.41
\linenopenalty=\count92
\output=\toks15
\linenoprevgraf=\count93
\linenumbersep=\dimen103
\linenumberwidth=\dimen104
\c@linenumber=\count94
\c@pagewiselinenumber=\count95
\c@LN@truepage=\count96
\c@internallinenumber=\count97
\c@internallinenumbers=\count98
\quotelinenumbersep=\dimen105
\bframerule=\dimen106
\bframesep=\dimen107
\bframebox=\box28
LaTeX Info: Redefining \\ on input line 3056.
)
\c@FV@TrueTabGroupLevel=\count99
\c@FV@TrueTabCounter=\count100
\FV@TabBox@Group=\box29
\FV@TmpLength=\skip43
\c@FV@HighlightLinesStart=\count101
\c@FV@HighlightLinesStop=\count102
\FV@LoopCount=\count103
\FV@NCharsBox=\box30
\FV@BreakIndent=\dimen108
\FV@BreakIndentNChars=\count104
\FV@BreakSymbolSepLeft=\dimen109
\FV@BreakSymbolSepLeftNChars=\count105
\FV@BreakSymbolSepRight=\dimen110
\FV@BreakSymbolSepRightNChars=\count106
\FV@BreakSymbolIndentLeft=\dimen111
\FV@BreakSymbolIndentLeftNChars=\count107
\FV@BreakSymbolIndentRight=\dimen112
\FV@BreakSymbolIndentRightNChars=\count108
\c@FancyVerbLineBreakLast=\count109
\FV@LineBox=\box31
\FV@LineIndentBox=\box32
\FV@LineWidth=\dimen113
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty
Package: calc 2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count110
\calc@Bcount=\count111
\calc@Adimen=\dimen114
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen115
\calc@Askip=\skip44
\calc@Bskip=\skip45
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
\calc@Ccount=\count112
\calc@Cskip=\skip46
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/shellesc.sty
Package: shellesc 2016/06/07 v0.02b unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
Package shellesc Info: Unrestricted shell escape enabled on input line 70.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifplatform/ifplatform.sty
Package: ifplatform 2017/10/13 v0.4a Testing for the operating system

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2019/07/25 v0.30 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2018/09/07 v3.3 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/catchfile.sty
Package: catchfile 2016/05/16 v1.7 Catch the contents of a file (HO)
)
runsystem(uname -s > "PraxisphaseAufsatz.w18")...executed.


(./PraxisphaseAufsatz.w18)
runsystem(rm -- "PraxisphaseAufsatz.w18")...executed.


Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \zap@space was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.94 ...\edef\@tempa{\expandafter\zap@space\@tempa
                                                  \@empty}
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \ip@only@six was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.104 ...ef\@tempc{\expandafter\ip@only@six\@tempa
                                                  ------\@nil}
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.104 ...expandafter\ip@only@six\@tempa------\@nil
                                                  }
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex
\integerpart=\count113
\decimalpart=\count114
)
Package: xstring 2019/02/06 v1.83 String manipulations (CT)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/framed/framed.sty
Package: framed 2011/10/22 v 0.96: framed or shaded text with page breaks
\OuterFrameSep=\skip47
\fb@frw=\dimen116
\fb@frh=\dimen117
\FrameRule=\dimen118
\FrameSep=\dimen119
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty
Package: float 2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
\c@float@type=\count115
\float@exts=\toks16
\float@box=\box33
\@float@everytoks=\toks17
\@floatcapt=\box34
)
\minted@appexistsfile=\read2
\minted@bgbox=\box35
\minted@code=\write4
\c@minted@FancyVerbLineTemp=\count116
\c@minted@pygmentizecounter=\count117
\@float@every@listing=\toks18
\c@listing=\count118
)
runsystem(mkdir -p _minted-PraxisphaseAufsatz)...executed.


(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
)
runsystem(which pygmentize && touch PraxisphaseAufsatz.aex)...executed.



! Package minted Error: You must have `pygmentize' installed to use this packag
e.

See the minted package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.5 \begin{document}

Refer to the installation instructions in the minted documentation for more inf
ormation.

(./PraxisphaseAufsatz.aux)
\openout1 = `PraxisphaseAufsatz.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count119
\scratchdimen=\dimen120
\scratchbox=\box36
\nofMPsegments=\count120
\nofMParguments=\count121
\everyMPshowfont=\toks19
\MPscratchCnt=\count122
\MPscratchDim=\dimen121
\MPnumerator=\count123
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count124
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks20
)
\openout3 = `PraxisphaseAufsatz.pyg'.

runsystem(pygmentize -S default -f latex -P commandprefix=PYG > _minted-Praxisp
haseAufsatz/default-pyg-prefix.pygstyle)...executed.



! Package minted Error: Missing Pygments output; \inputminted was
probably given a file that does not exist--otherwise, you may need 
the outputdir package option, or may be using an incompatible build tool,
or may be using frozencache with a missing file.

See the minted package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.11    \end{minted}^^M

This could be caused by using -output-directory or -aux-directory 
without setting minted's outputdir, or by using a build tool that 
changes paths in ways minted cannot detect, 
or using frozencache with a missing file.

runsystem(pygmentize -S default -f latex -P commandprefix=PYGdefault > _minted-
PraxisphaseAufsatz/default.pygstyle)...executed.


! Package minted Error: Missing Pygments output; \inputminted was
probably given a file that does not exist--otherwise, you may need 
the outputdir package option, or may be using an incompatible build tool,
or may be using frozencache with a missing file.

See the minted package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.11    \end{minted}^^M

This could be caused by using -output-directory or -aux-directory 
without setting minted's outputdir, or by using a build tool that 
changes paths in ways minted cannot detect, 
or using frozencache with a missing file.

runsystem(pygmentize -l c -f latex -P commandprefix=PYG -F tokenmerge -o _minte
d-PraxisphaseAufsatz/916909323916480C99F1AA97E621BB15219288A92FD0AFDEBD8CE6CF1E
55BAC6.pygtex PraxisphaseAufsatz.pyg)...executed.


! Package minted Error: Missing Pygments output; \inputminted was
probably given a file that does not exist--otherwise, you may need 
the outputdir package option, or may be using an incompatible build tool,
or may be using frozencache with a missing file.

See the minted package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.11    \end{minted}

This could be caused by using -output-directory or -aux-directory 
without setting minted's outputdir, or by using a build tool that 
changes paths in ways minted cannot detect, 
or using frozencache with a missing file.

(./PraxisphaseAufsatz.aux)
runsystem(rm PraxisphaseAufsatz.pyg)...executed.

runsystem(rm PraxisphaseAufsatz.out.pyg)...executed.

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 4533 strings out of 492167
 82218 string characters out of 6125388
 193966 words of memory out of 5000000
 8870 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 42i,1n,37p,833b,142s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

No pages of output.
PDF statistics:
 0 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Can you show the complete .log file?

Comment: Thanks for the log file! Can you try to update your tex distribution with `tlmgr update -self -all`? Some of the package are not up to date, maybe this causes the problem

Comment: Hi, I updated the distribution, but that did not seem to solve this problem. Going to update the log file in a minute

Comment: Great! Next test: does `pdflatex -shell-escape filename` from the CLI work?

Comment: In case the document compiles from CLI, check if python is in your texstudio path, e.g.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJnb9.png but with your anaconda path instead

Comment: Editing the texstudio path worked!
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the anaconda python binary is not already in the search path for all applications, it can be added to the texstudio search path via `Preferences->Build->Commands ($PATH)`

[image]

If this python version should be available for all applications, it can also be globally added to the path, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51677/how-to-set-path-for-finder-launched-applications (this might cause problems for applications that ship their own python version)

Comment: Any idea what the equivalent would be on Windows please?

Comment: @Colin No idea, sorry!

Comment: Hi @Colin 
Adding C:\Users\\*your_username*\\Anaconda3\Scripts to the build commands path worked for me